# Отправить запрос через file_get_contents без ожидания ответа

Tags: php

Задача, отправить запрос который будет долго выполняться на сервере и чтобы пользователь не ждал выполнения, нужно сразу после отправки запроса не ожидая ответа перекинуть пользователя на другую страницу.

Comment: Форкнуться - не?

Answer (score 1):

Я просто оставлю ссылку на уже отвеченный вопрос 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668762/272885
не буквально file_get_contents, но думаю то, что надо.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью CURL можно запросить только заголовки страницы.

```
<?php
  if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.ru');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
  }
?>
```